# How do you remove random text in a field in a mySQL table using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been working with a company that is half-way around the world converting a database.  They put a random set of text at the end of text inside columns in a table and I want to remove the text as easily as possible.  I don't want to hand-remove thousands of entries.

For example, I have a table called "Users".
The table "users" have many different fields, but the one I want to modify is called "username"
For that column, we have the following entries:

- Sam-ABC123
- Bob-ABC234
- Joe-ABC578

I could go into each row and change each entry so that it shows

- Sam
- Bob
- Joe

But I have 4,000 of these just on that field alone.  Quite time consuming and prone to error!

I've tried going into phpMyAdmin and do a search and replace but nothing changed.

I tried:

Find:  ABC%
REPLACE:  def
Column:  username

Preview shows all the tables, but the original string and replacement string are the same; nothing gets replaced

I tried:

Find:  ABC*
REPLACE:  def
Column:  username

Preview shows nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Export the database as an SQL file and perform a regex search and replace? Since the random value is delimited from the username with a dash that should be easy. After replacement simply reimport the SQL file. MySQL has no regex replacement capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Since phpMyAdmin allows you to execute any query, why don't you just do

```
UPDATE users SET username = SUBSTRING(username, 0, INSTR(username, '-') - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the dash character is used as a separator you can use a SQL query and [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
UPDATE users
SET username = SUBSTRING_INDEX(username, '-', 1)
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b392/1).

Comment: You are awesome!  Thank you!  Also thank you for showing me that play sand area.  I didn't know that existed!